# Does MySQL compress the stored data?

Tags: mysql

When I export a database in MySQL, it gives me a `.sql` file. Let's say this `.sql` file is 80 MB.

Are they compressed in order to reduce disk space usage?

Is that 80MB real physical-storage size?

Comment: The size in the database might actually be a lot higher because of indexes defined on the tables. The SQL only contains the index definition. The database stores the actual index data. Depending on the table/index size, this could mean that the database is a lot bigger than the 80mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you export your database:

if you use `mysqldump`, then the result is a flat text file containing the sql commands.

you can compress it manually or in one commandline like this:

```
mysqldump < mysqldump options> | gzip > outputfile.sql.gz
```

see: http://www.ducea.com/2006/10/28/compressing-mysqldump-output/

---

if your question is, if the tables are stored compressed in the working directory, there are some possibilities:

if you have MyISAM tables that would work if they are read-only, you can [Generate Compressed, Read-Only MyISAM Tables with myisampack](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisampack.html)

And by setting InnoDB configuration options, you can create tables where the data is stored in compressed form.

see: dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression.html

just alter the table to add the compressed option:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ENGINE = InnoDB ROW_FORMAT = COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE =4
```